# Remove all <p> tags from a string in JS using a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I know the subject has been treated many times on SO, but I couldn't fine a proper solution yet.

I have this string:

```
<p>Your account has been created on this application.</p>

<p><em>You are now connected as <strong>vado</strong>. Used language: <strong>en</strong>.</em></p>
```

I want to remove all `<p></p>` tags but not the content inside. I have tried several regexes but I wasn't able to delete them all so far.

I have tried `replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '')`, `replace(/(<([p^>]+)>)/ig)` but ...

Note that I need to use a regex here, a DOM jQuery manipulation is not possible.

Comment: Thanks brad for peer review, didn't see it. 3am here... ^^

Comment: I believe you're looking for `.replace(/<\/?p>/ig,'')`

Comment: Barmar: I didn't find the same exact question with an answer that worked for me and I looked for at least 20mn.